# Why is an object fetched from a string using JSON.parse not equal to the orignal Object converted using JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

Can someone explain why the following code would log false to the console?

```
const object = { title: 'object', data: 2 };
localStorage.setItem('object', JSON.stringify(object));
console.log(object === JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('object')));
```

Comment: Two objects in memory are not equal if they reside in different spaces in memory.

Comment: this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because by using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and then [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) you are converting your Object `type` to a `string` which is a new `Object` type which means it's a **new** object with it's own independent reference in memory, and by comparing the `objects` you are comparing their reference in memory that's why they are not equal.